# Build error "There must be only one argument: DEST_DIR "

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

After following the official RTD installation tutorial for ubuntu18 I manage to do everything (even webhooks) until the point of building, for a project called **test**, where I get the following error:

> python3.6 -mvirtualenv  /home/myuser/readthedocs.org/user_builds/test/envs/latest

Followed by:

> There must be only one argument: DEST_DIR (you gave  /home/gcsuser/readthedocs.org/user_builds/test/envs/latest)
> Usage: virtualenv.py [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

[image: THe output when building]

I haven't changed (nor I do know here) to change the DEST_DIR.
The debug.log states exactly what's on the image

Here is the total log after clicking the "Build" Button:
[`Full log in here`](https://pastebin.com/QQz6Rn47)

If I run the command "python3.6 -mvirtualenv  /home/myuser/readthedocs.org/user_builds/myprojecto/envs/latest" in the command line the result is the following:

> (venv) myuser@lxgcsrtd01:~/readthedocs.org$ python3.6 -mvirtualenv /home/myuser/readthedocs.org/user_builds/myprojecto/envs/latest
>
> Using real prefix '/usr'
>
> Path not in prefix '/home/myuser/readthedocs.org/venv/include/python3.6m' '/usr'
>
> New python executable in /home/myuser/readthedocs.org/user_builds/myprojecto/envs/latest/bin/python3.6
>
> Not overwriting existing python scrip /home/myuser/readthedocs.org/user_builds/myprojecto/envs/latest/bin/python (you must use /home/myuser/readthedocs.org/user_builds/myprojecto/envs/latest/bin/python3.6)
>
> Installing setuptools, pip, wheel... done. (venv)
>
> myuser@lxgcsrtd01:~/readthedocs.org$

Looks like, as the error states, there are two argumets, yet I can't find any space in bettween the arguments, and if I copy paste it to the shell it won't throw any errors.

Comment: Please provide a link to the build errors on RTD.

Comment: That's an image that provides no more information than your original question, which is still without sufficient information to answer. Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: more info added

Comment: Still not sufficient information. Sorry. I'd suggest comparing your build output with a successful build output from another project, like [pyramid_zcml](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyramid-zcml/builds/10823969/). Comparing, I see you are trying to get a remote repo from a secret IP address. I can't tell whether that actually worked as you expect. I also cannot tell whether you have configured your RTD build correctly. For that consult RTD's docs, especially its FAQ: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Comment: The secret ip addr is just a local git repository, the pull and push are working fine. The repository just has a simple sphynx test doc. I've gonne throght the FAQ and still no solution

Comment: Again, I would strongly recommend that you compare a working example with your failing example to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=python3.6 nameOfYourProject
```

[Pythonanywhere Documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango/)

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 django